# Property '*' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

The code:

I was trying to get all data from UsersData to print it in HTLM but I can't get it due to this error

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserData} from "../userData";
import {UserDataService} from "../userData.service";
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  public userDatas: UserData[];

  constructor(private dniService: UserDataService,private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUserDatas();
  }

  private getUserDatas() {
    this.dniService.getUserDatas().subscribe(
      (response: UserData[]) => {
        this.userDatas = response;
        console.log(this.userDatas);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
error TS2564: Property 'userDatas' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

12   public userDatas: UserData[];
```

What I tried:

--> public userDatas: UserData[] = [];
--> public userDatas: UserData[];

Anything of that worked

Answer (score 0):

You could add the exclamation mark to the end of the variable to indicate that you willingly have it uninitialised:

```
public userDatas!: UserData[];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public userDatas: UserData[] = [];
```

Are you sure this doesn't work? It certainly should.